# Can't display another Highcharts chart on my HTML page - Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, highcharts

Been looking at Highcharts doc and also "Integrating Django and Highcharts" by simpleisbetterthancomplex. I'm not sure what went wrong with my codes, that the second charts ain't display. I'm using Django views.py to retrieve data from the database.

```js
def dashboard_viewUser(request):
  dataset = Profile.objects\
  .values('is_active')\
  .annotate(is_active_count = Count('is_active', filter = Q(is_active = True)),
    not_is_active_count = Count('is_active', filter = Q(is_active = False)))\
  .order_by('is_active')

categories = list()
is_active_series_data = list()
not_is_active_series_data = list()

for entry in dataset:
  categories.append('%s Active' % entry['is_active'])
is_active_series_data.append(entry['is_active_count'])
not_is_active_series_data.append(entry['not_is_active_count'])

is_active_series = {
  'name': 'Active user',
  'data': is_active_series_data,
  'color': 'green'
}

not_is_active_series = {
  'name': 'Inactive user',
  'data': not_is_active_series_data,
  'color': 'red'
}

chart = {
  'chart': {
    'type': 'column'
  },
  'title': {
    'text': 'Active user on Current Platform'
  },
  'xAxis': {
    'categories': categories
  },
  'yAxis': {
    'title': {
      'text': 'No.of users'
    },
    'tickInterval': 1
  },
  'plotOptions': {
    'column': {
      'pointPadding': 0.2,
      'borderWidth': 0
    }
  },
  'series': [is_active_series, not_is_active_series]
}

dump = json.dumps(chart)

return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {
  'chart': dump
})
`
    
    def dashboard_viewDepartment(request):
        dataset = Department.objects \
            .values('department') \
            .annotate(IT_count=Count('department', filter=Q(department="IT")),
                      Sales_count=Count('department', filter=Q(department="Sales")),
                      Admin_count=Count('department', filter=Q(department="Admin")),
                      HR_count=Count('department', filter=Q(department="HR")),) \
            .order_by('department')
    
        categories = list()
        IT_series_data = list()
        Sales_series_data = list()
        Admin_series_data = list()
        HR_series_data = list()
    
        for entry in dataset:
            categories.append('%s Department' % entry['department'])
            IT_series_data.append(entry['IT_count'])
            Sales_series_data.append(entry['Sales_count'])
            Admin_series_data.append(entry['Admin_count'])
            HR_series_data.append(entry['HR_count'])
    
        IT_series = {
            'name': 'IT',
            'data': IT_series_data,
            'color': 'green'
        }
    
        Sales_series = {
            'name': 'Sales',
            'data': Sales_series_data,
            'color': 'yellow'
        }
    
        Admin_series = {
            'name': 'Admin',
            'data': Admin_series_data,
            'color': 'red'
        }
    
        HR_series = {
            'name': 'HR',
            'data': HR_series_data,
            'color': 'blue'
        }
    
        chart2 = {
            'chart': {'type': 'column'},
            'title': {'text': 'Containers per department'},
            'xAxis': {'categories': categories},
            'yAxis': {
                'title': {
                    'text': 'No.of containers'},
                'tickInterval': 1
                    },
            'plotOptions': {
                'column': {
                    'pointPadding': 0.2,
                    'borderWidth': 0
                }
            },
            'series': [IT_series, Sales_series, Admin_series, HR_series]
        }
    
        dump = json.dumps(chart2)
    
        return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {'chart2': dump})
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="border" id="container" style="min-width: 100px; height: 
                                400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      Highcharts.chart('container', {
        {
          chart | safe
        }
      });
    </script>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="border" id="container2" style="min-width: 100px; 
                               height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      Highcharts.chart('container2', {
        {
          chart2 | safe
        }
      });
    </script>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Currently Unavailable</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected two charts to be display on two different panel of the carousel

Comment: Hi @Django Newbie, Could you provide me the generated JS and HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

Actually You just need one script src of the highchart and jquery.min.js .
Change chart2 to chart.

```
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"> 
 </script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
 <div class="carousel-item active">
 <div class="border" id="container" style="min-width: 100px; height: 
      400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>       
  Highcharts.chart('container', {{ chart|safe }});
 </script>
 </div>
 <div class="carousel-item">
 <div class="border" id="container2" style="min-width: 100px; 
 height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

 <script>
                      Highcharts.chart('container2', {{ chart|safe }});
                  </script>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="carousel-caption" >
              <h3>Currently Unavailable</h3>
          </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But my second chart which is container2 is still not displaying :(

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple jquery/highchart. Just include it once at top of the page and it would work fine for multiple charts. I've updated your code a bit and since I don't have access to your data output from safe method, I've initialised the chart as a blank one.

```
  <!-- Place your javascripts once -->
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="border" id="container" style="min-width: 100px; height: 
                    400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

      <script>
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
          title: {
            text: 'Im Chart 1' // Replace your {{ chart|safe }} here.
          },
        });

      </script>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="border" id="container2" style="min-width: 100px; 
                   height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

      <script>
        Highcharts.chart('container2', {
          title: {
            text: 'Im Chart 2' //Replace your {{ chart2|safe }} here.
          },
        });

      </script>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Currently Unavailable</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Check out this fiddle for a working output.

https://jsfiddle.net/ebkr65ma/

Comment: I'm using {{ chart|safe }} because i have wrote all the chart description in my django views.py. I was able to display the first chart diagram but not the second one.

Comment: Can you try using the same chart output twice to see if your second chart variable is problematic?

Comment: I have added my django views.py not too sure if implemented the second chart right

Comment: I have zero knowledge of Python. However, wouldn't this only return the first chart then second ```chart2``` to be a null value?

Comment: Can you try replacing ```chart2``` on your html page to ```chart``` and see if it works. Then change ```chart``` instances to ```chart2``` to see if that works.

Comment: they displayed diagram with instance `chart` twice and when i tried changing to `chart2` it doesn't display anything

Comment: Then it's possible that Chart2 variable doesn't output a proper json. (I believe only the ```dashboard_viewUser``` works since it returns the total output.)

Comment: Small suggestion, can you move the whole ```dashboard_viewDepartment``` to the first function and assign the variable ```chart2``` for json dump. Then it should work if you pass along the chart2 variable into the view.

Comment: Has a solution ever been found for this?
I've come into the same issue and changing the container names helps to allow both scripts on the page, however the second chart is blank.